# What is the shortcut for fullscreen mode in Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard, fullscreen

Some apps allow their windows to be viewed in full screen, such as Google Chrome, which is really good.

Wondering if there is a shortcut to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works for Safari and Chrome.

The **^** is old unix style for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, which is why the option in the menu is:

[image]

**Edit:**

While the answer above only works for both Safari and Chrome, the following shortcut works only for Chrome and Firefox:

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Rant: iTunes uses ⌘f, so it's now impossibly hard to access the search/filter box with the keyboard only. Argh!

Comment: Not Rant: A caret (^) is the symbol for Control, old unix users represent copy/paste as ^c ^v. Aside from the incorrect capital F (IMO), that screenshot indicates 'Control+Command+f', and your answer indicates the same combination.

Comment: Ah, something new to remember! Still, it is somewhat unintuitive for the average user. BTW: You can access the iTunes search box via ALT+CMD+F.